# Realm does not seems to working

Tags: react-native, realm

I am trying to use realm in react-native android and I just wanted to test if it is working or not.
It seems to save data since it throws duplicated primaryKey error.
However, realm.objects('Person') does not return data but

```
Proxy
[[Handler]]
:
Object
[[Target]]
:
Results
[[IsRevoked]]
:
false  

 class Person {}
    Person.schema = {
      name: 'Person',
      primaryKey: 'name',
      properties: {
        name: 'string',
        age: {type: 'int', default: 0},
      },
    };

    const realm = new Realm({schema: [Person],schemaVersion: 2});

// Write
    realm.write(() => {
      const savedPerson = realm.create('Person', {
        name: 'Hal Incanden1za',
        age: 17,
      });
    });
    console.log(realm.objects('Person'))
```

Comment: may be you are trying to reload the app on emulator, and it is trying to overwrite the data which is already been stored.. try after you flush the storage or install it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value you get from a `realm.objects()` call is not a normal array, so `console.log` may not be doing what you are expecting here. Try iterating through it instead.